# Horizontal Scrolling of items in BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

In my app, I want to create a BottomNavigationBar having almost 10-15 items. Items should scroll in the horizontal orientation.
For example;

[image]
like this, items should be scrolled horizontally.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLight"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i hope i'm not mistaken but according to [material design for bottom navigation view](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#anatomy) it's recommended to have up to 5 items, plus it's recommend to use [material design navigation drawer or tabs](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/#standard-drawer)

Comment: @Bishan actually I'm new to Android development and just want a Horizontal scrollable layout in bottom same like BottomNavigationBar in which I want to add around 10 items and then display data as per item(Same like BottomNavigationBar).

Comment: If you want to make a horizontal list, don't use the bottom navigation view, and use a recyclerview with an horizontal orientation

Answer (score 0):

try one with this ,

https://github.com/huang3eng/CustomLayoutManager

it may helps you

Comment: The link pointed to does not (immediately) answer the question.